# How to create scatter and line chart in same chart view?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I know [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) lets you put two linecharts in the same plot but I need to plot 2 scatter charts and one line chart in the same graph. How can go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality you are describing is not available in versions of the library prior to v3.0.0

**EDIT**:

**As of v3.0.0+, this feature is now available**. It can be done using a `CombinedChart`. Check out the [example](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/CombinedChartActivity.java) to see how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is now available.  Check out the [CombinedChart example](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/CombinedChartActivity.java).

Comment: I would like to make a chart that is a scatter plot.  A scatter chart that has best fit line drawn through the chart.  Combined chart seems like such a mess is there a simpler way?  Like this https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/images/scatter-ice-cream1a.gif