# MPandroidchart Double YAxis with different scales

Tags: android, axis-labels, mpandroidchart

I want that my chart has two YAxis with different scales like the image . How I can change the scale for each axis?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried drawing two graphs and overlapping them?

Comment: This is not a good implementation

Comment: If you say so. Good luck finding a good one with this library then. Because in case you didn't read the documentation, it doesn't support such feature

Comment: Hellocharts library do this. But I really want to use mpandroidchart. Thank you for your advice. I will wait for a better solution.. In last case I will do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Version 2.0.0-beta](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/releases/tag/v2.0.0) was released over the weekend with a `CombinedChart`, which allows plotting Line-, Bar-, Scatter- and CandleData in one chart. So **the feature is finally available**.

One note about what I found during my upgrade, you can't simply addDataSet() for each one, you have to generate the individual DataSet types (Bar, Line, Scatter, etc) and then use SetData() for the appropriate type, to trigger rendering.

Here is the [example code](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/CombinedChartActivity.java).

Comment: Link is broken, it's always recommended to paste code instead of external link :)

Answer (score 4):

The author of MPAndroidChart library clearly specifies here, ([MPChart - Scatter Chart and LineChart in same plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570699/mpchart-scatter-chart-and-linechart-in-same-plot)), that this function is not yet available. So, I am also looking for a nicer approach.

As such, you can display two different chart types as one, still using this library, only by overlapping them.

I have done this on my side as it follows:

1. Edit the activity layout xml, having a FrameLayout as charts container.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    .......
    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/root_view">
    </FrameLayout>
    .......
</LinearLayout>
```

2. Now, in the Activity class, build the chart objects and attach them to the previous container:

```
    // construct the charts, as different objects
    // make sure to have valid Data Sets    
    LineChartItem lineChart = new LineChartItem(lineChartDataset, getApplicationContext());
    BarChartItem barChart = new BarChartItem(barChartDataset, getApplicationContext());

    // get the charts' container
    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_view);

    // populate the container with the charts' views
    frameLayout.addView(lineChart.getView(0, null, getApplicationContext()));
    frameLayout.addView(barChart.getView(1, null, getApplicationContext()));
```

**PROs/CONs** for such a practice:

**PROs**

You have more combined charts with MPAndroidChart.

**CONs**

You need to take care of X and Y Labels alignment.

User Events: only the upper (in Z order) Chart View will get the user input, so you need to make sure that all the other chart views behave in the same manner (either processing OR ignoring the input, like zooming the chart or value selection).

I hope for a quick release of this great lib having this option. Thank you in advance Philipp Jahoda!

Comment: Dude, the overlapping idea is a genious workaround, I never thought of that. I am currently working on combined charts, and the feature will likely be available within the next few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'd every thing as suggested by the `mpandroidcharts`

Still I was getting same scale on "**y axis right**" and "**y axis left**"

the culprit was

```
    combinedChart.axisLeft?.axisMinimum = //some calculations
    combinedChart.axisLeft?.axisMaximum = //some calculations
    combinedChart.axisRight?.axisMinimum = //some calculations
    combinedChart.axisRight?.axisMaximum = //some calculations
```

Basically a copy paste error when you copy your *perfect* code from bar or line chart where setting the axis minimum and maximum where required.